# how to give a DIV with position:absolute; the width of its content?

Tags: css

I am trying to let the width of a div to be expanded according to its content horizontally 
the content is a floating divs , I want them to appear as one row

I used `white-space: nowrap;` but it is not working on IE and FF ( It works very fine on google chrome ) 
here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="floating_menu_container">    
    <div class="floating_menu">
        <div class="floating_menu_item account">
            <div class="sub_floating_menu">
                <div class="sub_floating_menu_item"></div>
                <div class="sub_floating_menu_item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS code :

```
.floating_menu_container{
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
left: 5px;
height: 50px;
z-index: 5;
}

.floating_menu_container .floating_menu{
height: 0px;
width: 40px;
background: #4D75A6;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 7px;
}

.floating_menu_container .floating_menu .floating_menu_item{
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: #94acc9;
border: 1px solid #6991c2;
margin: 7px 0px 4px 4px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}

.floating_menu_container .floating_menu .floating_menu_item .sub_floating_menu{
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
background: #4D75A6;
left: 42px;
border: 1px solid #003980;
z-index: 10;
cursor: default;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.floating_menu_container .floating_menu .floating_menu_item .sub_floating_menu .sub_floating_menu_item{
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #94acc9;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

and here is the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUGbk/)

 I want to expand the div with class='sub_floating_menu' according to its content

Comment: Which div do you want to expand into which? have you tried `height:100%;width:100%;` ?

Comment: yes I did @iight but it is not working, I want to expand the div with class='sub_floating_menu' according to its content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `width: 20px;` from your `.sub_floating_menu_item`, `height: 30px;` from `.sub_floating_menu`, and replacing `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;` should fix the issue, little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/CZbne/5/).

Comment: @AymanJitan You have to remove `height: 30px;` from `.sub_floating_menu`: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/CZbne/2). No need to downvote, BTW.

Comment: sorry, but did you check your code on ie and firefox , it is not working , just working on google chrome

Comment: I am using Firefox 15.0.1 , also if you read the question carefully "the content is a floating divs , I want them to appear as one row"
and it appears on one row only on chrome , not working on ff and ie
thanks in advance buddy

Comment: @AymanJitan Replacing `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;` fixes the issue: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/CZbne/5/).

Comment: Please edit your answer with the correct link and the correct css code